# Does resuing pederson commitment preserve the hiding property?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, commitments

Assume you have a pedersen commitment scheme where the commitment is:
$$\mathcal C_1 =C(m,r)=g^m\cdot h^r$$
with $g,h$ being public generators in a public group $(G,\cdot)$ in which the discrete logarithm is hard. Assume now, we reuse this scheme to produce another commitment $C_2 = C(m, r') = g^m \cdot h^{r'}$ for the same message (but using another random value) and share that also.

Would generating two commitments in this scheme still preserve the perfect hiding property?
Also consider the case where we generate $C_1, \dots, C_n$ commitments for the message $m$. Could we - given those commitments - with non-negligible probability distinguish this from a series of commitments with $C'_1, \dots, C'_n$ that we generated for different messages, so $C_i = C(m_i, r_i)$, where $m_i \neq m_j$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$?

My intuition is that would not preserve the hiding property, since we could just divide the different commitments and observe a difference - is this correct?

Comment: Hint: Why does the Pedersen commitment normally achieve perfect hiding (i.e. how would you prove it)?

Comment: Thanks @SEJPM -- because multiple combinations of values $m,r$ would satisfy the given property $C(m,r) = g^m \cdot h^r$. This property seems to be lost in this specific scenario - correct?

Comment: Well, thinking along that line, now how $C(m,r)\neq C(m,r')$ (assuming $r\neq r'$) and thereby you again have multiple combinations of $m,r'$ that would satisfy $C(m,r')=g^m\cdot h^{r'}$

Comment: Aha! That means, for each $m$ there should will be a value $s$ that satisfies $C_1 = C(m,s)$ and thus there will be another value $s'$ that satisfies $C_2 = C(m, s')$. Thus, even if we would know that $C_1$ and $C_2$ were generated from the same $m$, we would have now way of realizing what $m$ this would be. Correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed (at least until the commitment is opened ;).